# Any ides how he added border in his reports?

Tags: tableau-api

Could any one please suggest how this guy added underline borders to his reports.

[image]

Link to report : https://public.tableau.com/en-us/gallery/how-much-do-ncaa-athletic-departments-profit?tab=featured&topic=social-good

Answer (score 1):

Those formatted lines have been achieved by

All in a dashboard:

1. Put the worksheet inside a container
2. Add Outer Padding by clicking on the worksheet then selecting 'Layout' on the left pane
   [image: Outer Padding View]
3. Then select the layout container (More Options > Select Layout Container) and format the background to Grey.

[image]

So the container is grey, with a white background worksheet inside and 2px of padding added to the bottom of the sheet, revealing some grey

Answer (score 0):

You can download the workbook and find out.
[image]

[image]